# Do modern LED lights use thermal vias?

Tags: led

I have a technical question about thermal management with mid-power LED diodes like Samsung LM301H.

Do you use thermal vias on the PC board anymore? Either under the LED diode footprint or even around the footprint?
[image: 1696523248761.png]

I was reading about this on a ten year old application note from Cree called "[Optimizing PCB Thermal Performance for XLamp® XQ & XH Family LEDs](https://downloads.cree-led.com/files/da/x/XLamp-PCB-Thermal-XQ-XH.pdf)"

Is this still a thing they do?

Answer (score 11):

Aluminium PCBs are quite popular, especially for applications where the total LED quantity and/or power is high (e.g. COBs).

Aluminium is used as the substrate, and the PCB tracks are isolated from it. Different materials are available for different isolation requirements.

This aluminium PCB can be directly attached to the heatsink.

> Do you use thermal vias on the PC board anymore? Either under the LED diode footprint or even around the footprint?

Depends on the application limits and cost targets.

Comment: Thank you Rohat Kılıç. Do the LED bar lights and quantum boards that are commonly seen use thermal vias in their PC board design? I don't think they are using aluminum PCB substrate.

Comment: @FXS quantum boards that I've ever seen are made of alu PCBs. LED bars, at least the ones I have designed in the past, were both alu and FR4. For FR4 PCBs I used thinner boards (1 or 1.2mm) with vias but no or little solder mask on the bottom side, and used thermally conductive tapes to transfer the PCB heat to the mounting profile (generally aluminium) whilst maintaining electrical isolation.

Comment: Are all PCB tracks isolated from the substrate or is e.g. ground connected to it? If not, how is the heat conducted?

Comment: A couple of side notes: boards *only* carrying LEDs are generally single layer for low cost, so through vias are unavailable. With LEDs connected in series, each LED (and the copper under it) is at a different potential, so connecting the substrate to any one potential would be fairly ineffective.

Comment: @BartvanHeukelom Heat conduction is basically through pure brute surface area. Almost the whole copper layer is flood-filled, and that copper is only separated from the aluminium by a very thin insulating layer, not a full thickness of FR4. Even where FR4 is used, again the top surface of the board is all copper so that the full area of the PCB is available to dissipate/transfer heat, even if the fibreglass isn't particularly effective at it. Engineering work needs to be done in terms of (mili)watts per cm^2 and the design temp of the chassis the PCBs are mounted to.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of lighting products, often thermal vias are used with FR4 as a lower cost alternative to an aluminum PCB or in boards where the total LED heat is low enough that aluminum is unnecessary. For things like quantum boards which are relatively high end arrays of diodes, an aluminum PCB is justified, so you won't see FR4+ thermal vias.

In general use thermal vias are extremely common, both for LEDs and chips of all kinds.